# Jquery each loop to get json data

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have this data in json and I want to load it and use it in the localStorage.

```
[
{
    "name": "Dexter",
    "year": "2006",
    "rating": "88%",
    "from": "USA",
    "kind": "crime / drama / thriller",
    "length": "96x55 min",
    "characters": [
      {
         "name": "Dexter Morgan",
         "actor": "Michael C. Hall"
      },
      {
         "name": "Debra Morgan",
         "actor": "Jennifer Carpenter"
      },
      {
         "name": "Angel Batista",
         "actor": "David Zayas"
      },
      {
         "name": "Hannah McKay",
         "actor": "Yvonne Strahovski"
      },
      {
         "name": "Joey Quinn",
         "actor": "Desmond Harrington"
      }
    ]
}, ... (+other tv series)]
```

This is my code to load data and get it to var jsonObj, which I use to load it to localStorage.

function loadData(){

```
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
     $.each(data, function(key, val){

          var charactersArray = [];

          $.each(data.characters, function(key, val){

              charactersArray += {
                    name: val.name,
                    actor: val.actor
              };
          }); 

          var jsonObj = { 
                          name: val.name, 
                          year: val.year, 
                          rating: val.rating, 
                          from: val.from, 
                          kind: val.kind,  
                          length: val.length, 
                          characters: charactersArray
                        };....
```

The only thing that does not work here is the iteration to get values to charactersArray. It is empty, only includes [] in the result. Can somebody help me fix this to get the identic data to the var jsonObj? Thank you very much.

Comment: `charactersArray.push({
                    name: val.name,
                    actor: val.actor
              });`

Comment: why are you using += ?

Comment: Why don't you just do `var charactersArray = val.characters`? You don't seem to be doing anything special in the inner `each` loop and it seems redundant

Comment: Also note there is no `data.characters` since `data` is an array of objects that each contain `characters`

Comment: thanks, it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited some part of code as follow hope this will work.

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
      var charactersArray = [];

      $.each(val.characters, function(ChildKey, ChildVal){
          charactersArray += {
                name: ChildVal.name,
                actor: ChildVal.actor
          };
      }); 

      var jsonObj = { 
                      name: val.name, 
                      year: val.year, 
                      rating: val.rating, 
                      from: val.from, 
                      kind: val.kind,  
                      length: val.length, 
                      characters: charactersArray
                    };});
```